# woocommerce shipping cost doesn't show on the cart page until address is inserted

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My problem is that my cart page doesn't show me shipping cost.

I found this message on thecart page:

[image: see this]

I want to show my shipping cost on the cart page. How can I do this?

My woocommerce shipping settings are

[image: click here]

I have not found any solution to directly show my shipping cost before putting my address and I don’t want my buyer to select calculator option. Tell me any function that by default enable my shipping cost to show on my cart and checkout page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your shipping settings, insert custom zone and country and set the method. If you are transporting to an unsupported country then you should select from the main woocommerce settings 'sell to specific country' and then you are done.

Now it will show your shipping cost or methods on cart page without entering your address.

Comment: Even in WC 5.0 this sickly behavior is still there. Thx for solving this extremely annoying and seemingly illogical problem.

Answer (score 0):

And in Woo 3.5 is ab bug, use 3.5.1, there this issue is fixed.